# Is it possible to access a variable created in a function, outside of that function in swift 4

Tags: swift

I need to access a variable created inside a function I have made earlier in the script, but when I enter the variable name, it says `use of unresolved identifier`. I have been trying to figure out ways to fix this problem but nothing comes to mind. Thanks for your help.

Here is the function I created earlier in the script, and the variable I need to access is `location.x`

```
 override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        var location = touch.location(in: self.view)
            
        _ = location.x
        location.x = location.x - 43
        
        Head.frame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(location.x), y: 451,width: Head.frame.size.width,height: Head.frame.size.height)
```

And here is where I need to put `location.x` later in the code.

```
if eggOney == 431 && location.x == location.x + 0...86
```

Comment: Please add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't help you if you don't show us your code.

Comment: Add a property to your class and set it in the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to save the variable in your class:

```
var xLocation: Double // you may want to initialize it (or make optional)

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    ...
    self.xLocation = location.x
}
```

and later you can access it:

```
if eggOney == 431 && location.x == self.xLocation + 0.86
```

Comment: Thank you everyone who has helped me with this question. I have now almost got it working apart from the fact that it now says -Cannot convert value of type 'CGFloat' to expected argument type 'ClosedRange<CGFloat>'-

Comment: @Hugh This probably isn't connected with the problem in your question. Where do you get this error?

Comment: if eggOney == 431 && xLocation == xLocation + 0...86 {
                    
                }

Comment: @Hugh You can't just add a Range to a number. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to make it so that xLocation can have a larger area for the if so it is not just in one place where the if work

Comment: @Hugh I recommend you create another post with your new question and describe your problem in detail. I'll try to help you there :)